# disable users from logging in with their Snowflake username and password

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, single-sign-on, okta

We just moved Snowflake behind Okta. One of the test users is still able to login with their username and password, but we want to be able to not allow users from doing that and just to login with their Okta credentials.

The docs we followed were Steps 1, 2, and 4, however I don't see in this article how to disable users from logging in w. the Snowflake username and password.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Setup-SSO-Using-Okta-with-Snowflake-new-URL-format

Comment: Have you tried removing their password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once SSO is set up and you know it works (test it out with a few users), you can just `UNSET` their password:

```
ALTER USER put_their_username_here UNSET PASSWORD;
```

You will need to do that for each individual user that has a password. They should not be able to give themselves a password again either, unless they have the `SECURITYADMIN` or `ACCOUNTADMIN` roles.

Any new user should be created and managed in Okta and will not have a password attached to their user by default.